# Multithreaded Executor channel to speed up the consumer process

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a message producer which produces around 15 messages/second

The consumer is a spring integration project which consumes from the Message Queue and does a lot of processing. Currently it is single threaded and not able to match with the rate at which the producer are sending the messages. hence the queue depth keeps on increasing

```
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(Jms.container(this.emsConnectionFactory, this.emsQueue).get()))
                .wireTap(FLTAWARE_WIRE_TAP_CHNL)// push raw fa data
                .filter(ingFilter, "filterMessageOnEvent").transform(eventHandler, "parseEvent")
                .aggregate(a -> a.correlationStrategy(corStrgy, "getCorrelationKey").releaseStrategy(g -> {

                    boolean eonExists = g.getMessages().stream()
                            .anyMatch(eon -> ((FlightModel) eon.getPayload()).getEstGmtOnDtm() != null);
                    if (eonExists) {
                        boolean einExists = g.getMessages().stream()
                                .anyMatch(ein -> ((FlightModel) ein.getPayload()).getEstGmtInDtm() != null);
                        if (einExists) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }).messageStore(this.messageStore)).channel("AggregatorEventChannel").get();
```

is it possible to use executor channel to process this in a multithreaded environment and speed up the consumer process

If yes, please suggest how can i achieve - To ensure ordering of the messages I need to assign the messages of same type (based on the id of the message) to the same thread of the executor channel.

**[UPDATED CODE]**
I have created the below executor channels

```
    public static final MessageChannel SKW_DEFAULT_CHANNEL = MessageChannels
            .executor(ASQ_DEFAULT_CHANNEL_NAME, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)).get();

    public static final MessageChannel RPA_DEFAULT_CHANNEL = MessageChannels
            .executor(ASH_DEFAULT_CHANNEL_NAME, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)).get();
```

Now from the main message flow I redirected to a custom router which forwards the message to Executor channel as shown below -

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow baseEventFlow1() {

        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(Jms.container(this.emsConnectionFactory, this.emsQueue).get()))
                .wireTap(FLTAWARE_WIRE_TAP_CHNL)// push raw fa data
                .filter(ingFilter, "filterMessageOnEvent").route(route()).get();
    }

    public AbstractMessageRouter router() {
        return new AbstractMessageRouter() {
            @Override
            protected Collection<MessageChannel> determineTargetChannels(Message<?> message) {
                if (message.getPayload().toString().contains("\"id\":\"RPA")) {
                    return Collections.singletonList(RPA_DEFAULT_CHANNEL);
                } else if (message.getPayload().toString().contains("\"id\":\"SKW")) {
                    return Collections.singletonList(SKW_DEFAULT_CHANNEL);
                } else {
                    return Collections.singletonList(new NullChannel());
                }
            }

        };
    }
```

I will have individual consumer flow for the corresponding executor channel.

Please correct my understaning

**[UPDATED]**

```
    @Bean
    @BridgeTo("uaxDefaultChannel")
    public MessageChannel ucaDefaultChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.executor(UCA_DEFAULT_CHANNEL_NAME, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)).get();
    }

    @Bean
    @BridgeTo("uaDefaultChannel")
    public MessageChannel ualDefaultChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.executor(UAL_DEFAULT_CHANNEL_NAME, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)).get();
    }
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow uaEventFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("uaDefaultChannel").wireTap(UA_WIRE_TAP_CHNL)
                .transform(eventHandler, "parseEvent")
}
```

So BridgeTo on the executor channel will forward the messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> hence the queue depth keeps on increasing

Since it looks like your queue is somewhere on JMS broker that is really OK to have such a behavior. That's exactly for what messaging systems have been designed - to distinguish producer and consumer and deal with messages in a destination whenever it is possible.

if you want to increase a polling from JMS, you can consider to have a `concurrency` option on the JMS container:

```
/**
 * The concurrency to use.
 * @param concurrency the concurrency.
 * @return current {@link JmsDefaultListenerContainerSpec}.
 * @see DefaultMessageListenerContainer#setConcurrency(String)
 */
public JmsDefaultListenerContainerSpec concurrency(String concurrency) {
    this.target.setConcurrency(concurrency);
    return this;
}

/**
 * The concurrent consumers number to use.
 * @param concurrentConsumers the concurrent consumers count.
 * @return current {@link JmsDefaultListenerContainerSpec}.
 * @see DefaultMessageListenerContainer#setConcurrentConsumers(int)
 */
public JmsDefaultListenerContainerSpec concurrentConsumers(int concurrentConsumers) {
    this.target.setConcurrentConsumers(concurrentConsumers);
    return this;
}

/**
 * The max for concurrent consumers number to use.
 * @param maxConcurrentConsumers the max concurrent consumers count.
 * @return current {@link JmsDefaultListenerContainerSpec}.
 * @see DefaultMessageListenerContainer#setMaxConcurrentConsumers(int)
 */
public JmsDefaultListenerContainerSpec maxConcurrentConsumers(int maxConcurrentConsumers) {
    this.target.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(maxConcurrentConsumers);
    return this;
}
```

See more info the Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jms-receiving

But that won't allow you to "asign messages to the specific thread". There is just like no way to partition in JMS.

We can do that with Spring Integration using `router` according your "based on the id of the message" and particular `ExecutorChannel` instances configured with a singled-threaded `Executor`. Every `ExecutorChannel` is going to be its dedicated executor with only single thread. This way you will ensure an order for messages with the same partition key and you'll process them in parallel. All the `ExecutorChannel` can have the same subscriber or `bridge` to the same channel for processing.

However you need to keep in mind that when you are leaving JMS listener thread, you finish JMS transaction and you fail to process a message in that separate thread you may lose a message.

Comment: Thanks Artem. I am in initial days with Spring integration, sorry if I am asking invalid queries. So as per my understanding, if we implement router and based on the id of the message forward it to the executor channel then we don't need to set the JMS concurrent consumers, correct? Also, would it be possible to share a quick link or example snippet on how we can route it to a particular Executor Channel based on any attribute, Thanks

Comment: Right, you don't need concurrency on concurrency. The router configuration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-routers

Comment: Thanks Artem. So I am creating separate Executorchannel with thread pool size as 1. I have updated my original question with the changes. Can you please tell me if I am going in the correct direction. Thanks for your help

Comment: Your understanding is correct. And implementation looks good. You many consider to use a dedicated `route()` EIP with the `Function` to avoid that `AbstractMessageRouter` implementation, but for now your code is OK: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/message-routing.html#router

Comment: Thank you Artem, Sorry to bug you so much :). I have another question if i separate this out into multiple executors and then read each executor channel using IntegrationFlows.from(exec channel1), I have the same processing pipeline or flow, so I have to mention the same transformer or the handler method in all the Integration Flows. Is there any better way to handle it

Comment: Right, you can that common logic as a standalone `IntegrationFlow` starting from some reasonable channel. All your those `ExecutorChannel` beans could be marked with the `@BridgeTo` for the same channel which starts that common flow.

Comment: Thank you Artem, I have updated the modified code in my original question. Please let me know if this looks ok.  I don't queue piling up in my JMS broker band the conusmer thread is constantly processing it. Is it storing the messages in memory?